# Unexpected Identifier when trying to wrap span tag around list text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which creates list items based on an object. I'm having a lot of issues styling the list because many of them are nested within each other. I tried adding a span around the text so I could target the span. However, I get error `Unexpected identifier`

```
function traverseMap(obj, element) {
      for (var key in obj) {
          var item = obj[key];

          var li = $('<li>', {
                  text: "<span>"+item.title+"</span>",
                  title: item.title,
                  value: item.url
              }).appendTo(element);

          if (!$.isEmptyObject(item.children)) {
              var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo(li);
              traverseMap(item.children, ul);
          }
      }
  }
  traverseMap(map, $('#expList'));
}
```

Comment: Missing a `+` after title.. `text: "<span>"+item.title"</span>",`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains typo

Comment: I fixed the typo but I get the same error. I updated OP

Comment: not sure but too maybe there should be html: instead of text:

Comment: let me try, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Check your console for these kind of errors... It will point to the exxact location...

Comment: Its still wrong, `+` should be outside quotes.

Comment: @Peminator, you were right. Changing text to HTML fixed the issue for me. Thank you.